# How to remove the watermark on my desktop in test signing mode?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization, watermark

My Windows is in Test Signing mode and I want to keep it that way as I'm a developer.

However, is there a way that I can get rid of the

```
Test Mode
Windows 7
Build 7600
```

in the bottom right corner of the wallpaper on my desktop?

This in not a duplicate of [How to remove the test mode watermark on wallpaper?](https://superuser.com/questions/290195/windows-7-how-to-remove-the-test-mode-watermark-on-wallpaper) as they disable it there.

Is there a way to automate this so that it remains or is applied again after updates that roll back the edits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run a program downloaded off the internet... Google "remove watermark test mode".

[This post](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/712994-any-easy-way-to-remove-test-mode-label-from-the-desktop#entry590311808) says that deleting these registry keys (or more likely renaming them) will work:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\CA\Certificates\FEE449EE0E3965A5246F000E87FDE2A065FD89D4]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\ROOT\Certificates\2BD63D28D7BCD0E251195AEB519243C13142EBC3]
```

You can also [edit user32.dll.mui](http://www.mydigitallife.info/remove-and-disable-windows-vista-evaluation-watermark-from-desktop/) with a resource editor or even a simple hex editor to replace the strings with null values or spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your quick summary. Hmm, I'm wondering what other effects removing a root certificate would have. Perhaps I could set the program to run on each boot, or trigger it to run after updates. Maybe I should look into the ability to remove it from the live GUI (by obtaining the handle and removing the labels)...

Comment: @Tom: You could always just edit the user32.dll.mui...